# Map only a sub-property in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have two classes which come from a library, i.e. cannot be altered by me:

```
public class EntityInfo
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    //... some other properties
}
public class MyEntity
{
    public Guid MyEntityId { get; set; }
    public EntityInfo AnotherEntityInfo { get; set; }
    //... some other properties
}
```

I need to map MyEntity to a table with these columns:

```
MyEntityId uniqueidentifier,
AnotherEntityId uniqueidentifier -- Here the value of AnotherEntityInfo.Id should be mapped
-- ... some other properties
```

I don't need to map the other properties of the type EntityInfo, just the Id. So it is like flattening EntityInfo and taking only its Id. Again, I cannot change the classes MyEntity and EntityInfo

Does anyone know a way to do so?

Comment: Two classes to one table. That's table splitting or complex type. It depends on primary key requirements what you can do. Maybe you can take a look using these key words.

Answer (score 1):

You need update ForeignKey for class MyEntity such as:

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public Guid MyEntityId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("AnotherEntityInfo")]
    public int AnotherEntityInfoId { get; set; }
    public EntityInfo AnotherEntityInfo { get; set; }
    //... some other properties
}
```

you can read here: [source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx)

Comment: I did this and selections work, e.g.: MyEntities.FirstOrDefault(x => x.AnotherEntityInfo.Id == id). The select from the database is correct but the AnotherEntityInfo property is null in the resulting MyEntity object.

Comment: One more thing: AnotherEntityInfo is not saved in the database, it is like a "complex type" of which only one property is saved and it is save directly in the MyEntity table.

Answer (score 1):

> Again, I cannot change the classes MyEntity and EntityInfo

Then [Fluent configuration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx) is the only choice you have.

Override your `DbContext` derived class `OnModelCreating` method as follows:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>()
        .HasRequired(e => e.AnotherEntityInfo)
        .WithMany()
        .Map(c => c.MapKey("AnotherEntityInfoId"));

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

**EDIT:** I misunderstood the question. If `EntityInfo` is not an entity and is used **only** in `MyEntity`, then you can use the following fluent configuration:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // Ignore all the properties except Id    
    modelBuilder.ComplexType<EntityInfo>()
        .Ignore(e => e.Property1)
        .Ignore(e => e.Property2)
        ...
        .Ignore(e => e.PropertyN);

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

The above will create `AnotherEntityInfo_Id` column in `MyEntity` table. I didn't find a way to specify the column name.